# Prove that $\mathscr B$ is a basis for topology $\mathscr T$ on $\mathbb R$. Is $\mathscr T$ is a usual topology on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}$ and $\mathscr{B}=\{(a,b):a<b\}\cup \{(a,b)\setminus A:a<b\}.$ Prove that $\mathscr B$ is a basis for topology $\mathscr T$ on $\mathbb R$. Is $\mathscr T$ is a usual topology on $\mathbb R$?

Obviously,
(1)$\bigcup_{a,b\in \mathbb R}(a,b)=\mathbb R$
 For the second condition of basis,
(2)**Case 1:-**

Let $x\in B_1,B_2\in \{(a,b):a<b\}$ , then obviously there exists $x\in B_3$ such that $B_3\subset B_1 \cap B_3$

**Case2:-**$x\in B_1\in \{(a,b):a<b\}$and $B_2 \in\{(a,b)\setminus A:a<b\}$ I am not able to prove existance of $B_3$ such that $B_3\subset B_1 \cap B_3$

**Case 3** $B_1,B_2 \in\{(a,b)\setminus A:a<b\}$. How do I prove formally the existance of $B_3$?

to check whether the given basis generate usual topology or not?
 any open set can be generated by using $\{(a,b):a<b\}$.
Please check my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you have to check is

> For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, and all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there exists a $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

(A condition you sloppily reproduce, be more exact there!)

Now there are indeed cases to consider: suppose $B_1 = (a_1,b_1)$ and $B_2 = (a_2,b_2)$, so they are of "standard type". If we have $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then you can note that $B_1 \cap B_2 = (\max(a_1,a_2), \min(b_1,b_2))$ (the intersection is non-empty, so $\max(a_1,a_2) < \min(b_1,b_2)$ and we can use this intersection as our $B_3$ for all $x$ in the intersection.

You state "it's obvious" and go on. Your thoughts are probably along these lines: (but do make them explicit next time): $B_1$ and $B_2$ are standard open. So their intersection is standard open and the "standard type" open intervals already form a base for those, so the condition follows from open intervals being a base for the standard topology.

("existance" should be "existence")

If $B_1, B_2$ are of type two, an open interval minus $A$ (this case you skipped): You can use the observation above that the intersection of two open intervals is an interval or empty. So if non-empty, we can use $B_1 \cap B_2$ again for all points in it, as

$$((a,b) \setminus A) \cap ((c,d) \setminus A) = ((a,b) \cap (c,d)) \setminus A$$

If $B_1$ is of standard type $(a,b)$ and $B_2$ is of type two,  $B_2 = (c,d)\setminus A$ for some $c< d$, then note that if $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there are two subcases: a. $x \neq 0$, then $x \notin \overline{A}$ (closure in the standard topology, this holds as $\overline{A} = A \cup \{0\}$, which is standard closed. In that case we have $x \in (a,b) \cap (c,d) \cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus \overline{A})$ which is standard open (!) so there is some open interval (as these form a base for the standard topology!) $(e,f)$ with $$x \in (e,f) \subseteq (a,b) \cap (c,d) \cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus \overline{A}) \subseteq 
B_1 \cap B_2$$ as required.

The other subcase is $x = 0$. Then $0 \in (a,b) \cap (c,d)$ which is an interval $I$ containing $0$ again, and then $x \in B_3:= I \setminus A \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$ again.

So the condition checks out again.

Note that this topology could also have been defined by stating that

$\mathcal{S} = \{(a,b): a < b\} \cup \{\mathbb{R} \setminus A\}$ is a subbase for and then the finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{S}$ is exactly the collection $\mathcal{S}$, which is then a base by virtue of being a set of finite intersections from this family. If the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is *not* used in the intersection, we get open intervals, and if it is, we get an open interval minus $A$, i.e. type two.

It's clear that $A$ is not closed in the usual topology, but this topology is constructed by adding it as a new closed set, so it's strictly finer than the usual topology, as $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is open in it.

Comment: In the part of your answer where you stated that $((a_1,b_1) /A))\cap ((a_2,b_2)/A)=((a_1,b_1)\cap(a_2,b_2))/A$ I had thought at first glance that you were using De Morgans law but that states $A'\cap B' = (A\cup B)'$ may I ask was that a typo ?

Comment: @excalibirr no, not a typo, the statement is a fact about intersection and difference. Show it by two inclusions if you don’t know it.

Comment: Sorry I just realised my mistake , of course it's not related to De Morgans laws at all!! I'm actually very new to topology and find set relations very difficult to picture, do you know of any links that go through these type of set relations ?

Answer (score 2):

The assertion “there exists $x\in B_3$ such that $B_3\subset B_1 \cap B_3$” doesn't make sense because no $B_3$ has been defined at this point. What you should prove is that *for each* $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, there *exists* some $B_3\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_3$ and that $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.

And $\mathcal B$ doesn't generate the usual topology, since $A^\complement\in\mathcal B$ and $A^\complement$ doesn't belong to the usual topology. The topology generated by $\mathcal B$ is strictly finer that the usual one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Bbb B_1=\{(a,b):a,b\in \Bbb R\}$ and $\Bbb B_2=\{\beta \setminus A: \beta \in \Bbb B_1\}$ and $\Bbb B=\Bbb B_1\cup \Bbb B_2.$

(I). The condition $$\forall b,b'\in \Bbb B\;\forall x\in b\cap b'\;\exists b''\in \Bbb B\;(x\in b''\subset b\cap b')$$ is satisfied IF $$\forall b,b'\in \Bbb B\;(b\cap b'\in \Bbb B)$$ is satisfied.

If  $b,b'  \in  \Bbb B$  let $b=c \setminus d$ and $b'= c'\setminus d'$ where $c,c'\in \Bbb B_1$ and each of $d,d'$ is either $\emptyset$ or $A.$ Observe that  $c\cap c'\in B_1$. And $d\cup d'\in \{\emptyset,A\}$. So $$b\cap b'=(c\cap c')\setminus (d\cup d')\in \{(c\cap c'),\; (c\cap c')\setminus A \}\subset \Bbb B.$$

(II). Let $T_{\Bbb B}$ be the topology generated by the base (basis) $\Bbb B.$ Then $A$ is closed with respect to $T_{\Bbb B}$ because $\Bbb R \setminus A $ is the union of  $$(-1,1)\setminus A$$ with $$\bigcup \{(n,n+1): 1\leq n\in \Bbb Z \lor -1\geq n\in \Bbb Z\}$$ so $\Bbb R \setminus A \in T_{\Bbb B}.$

But with respect to the "usual" topology on $\Bbb R$ the set $A$ is not closed.

Footnote. If $B$ is a family of subsets of a set $X$ then the conditions $\cup B=X$ and $\forall b,b'\in B\;(b\cap b'\in B)$ are sufficient for $B$ to be a base (basis) for a topology on $X.$

Comment: Observe that if $T_U$ is the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ then $T_{\Bbb B}=T_U\cup \{t\setminus A:t\in T_U\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at Case 2. We let $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ be an arbitrary element of the intersection, where $B_1=(a,b)$ and $B_2=(c,d)\setminus A$. Note that since $x\in B_2$, we have that $x\not\in A$. Now consider the set $C=(max\{a,c\},min\{b,d\})\setminus A$. Because $a<x<b$, $c<x<d$, and $x\not\in A$, we can conclude that $x\in C$. It is easy to verify that $C\subset B_1\cap B_2$.

Case 3 is similar.

This topology is also introduced as "The K topology on $\mathbb{R}$" in Munkres *Topology*, and there are many examples using this topology in sections 12 through 19.